# onCreateOptionsMenu isn't being called inside Fragments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I know that this question has been asked quite a few times since I searched all over for an answer, but, sadly, I failed to find an answer mainly due to the fact that no one seems to be using the base Android classes for Fragments & instead they all use the Sherlock Fragment Class.

So first of all, I am not using any Sherlock Activity stuff or the Android Support Library. I'm just using the default Fragment class:

```
import android.app.Fragment
import android.view.Menu
import.android.view.MenuItem
import.android.view.View
//& so on...
```

This is onCreateView inside my Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return root;
}
```

& this is onCreateOptionsMenu also inside the same Fragment

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1_menu, menu);

//A lot of other code here

return super.getActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

My base Main FragmentActivity class doesn't have an onCreateOptionsMenu itself but I don't suppose that, that should affect the Fragments.

Also, I cannot seem to override onCreateOptionsMenu, the error I get is; onCreateOptionsMenu must override or implement a supertype method.

So please if anyone has any ideas that could resolve this, I'd really appreciate it!

Thank you so much!

Comment: call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your `onCreate(..)` in the Fragment

Comment: Make sure your Activity calls super.onCreateOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature for `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is different in a `Fragment` than in an `Activity`, as is shown in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater%29).

Change your implementation to:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1_menu, menu);

   //A lot of other code here

   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```